# binning an array to create sum domains array

Tags: image, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica - how do I bin an array to create a new array which consist from sum domains of the old array with a given size ???

Example:

[image]

thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why this question has been tagged with *image* and *image-processing*.  *Mathematica* has an extensive range of image processing functionality, including `ImagePartition` which can, well, partition an image into blocks for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the example but a generalised version would need more work.

```
array =
  {{1, 1, 1, 2},
   {1, 1, 3, 4},
   {2, 2, 2, 3},
   {2, 2, 2, 3}};

Map[Total,
 Map[Flatten,
  Map[Transpose,
   Map[Partition[#, 2] &, Partition[array, 2], 2],
   2], {2}], {2}]

% // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> 4 10
> 8 10
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly simpler than @ChrisDegnen's solution.  Given the same definition of `array` the expression

```
Map[Total, Map[Flatten, Partition[array, {2, 2}], {2}], {2}]
```

produces

```
{{4, 10}, {8, 10}}
```

If you prefer, this expression

```
Apply[Plus, Map[Flatten, Partition[array, {2, 2}], {2}], {2}]
```

uses `Apply` and `Plus` rather than `Map` and `Total` but is entirely equivalent.